# Django haystack Syntax error

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, syntax-error, django-haystack

I am trying to run a Django project that works fine on my collegue's machine, but I get an error from haystack when trying to runserver.

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/__init__.py", line 124, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 821, in _gcd_import
    loader.load_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 436, in load_module
    return self._load_module(fullname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 141, in decorated
    return fxn(self, module, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 342, in _load_module
    exec(code_object, module.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from haystack.utils import loading
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/haystack/utils/__init__.py", line 28
    raise AttributeError(u"Provided string '%s' is not a valid identifier." % obj_or_string)
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have haystack included in your installed apps.

Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-44-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 19:36:14 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Python 3.2.3

pip 6.0.8 from /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages (python 3.2)

```
Name: django-haystack
Version: 2.3.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages
Requires: Django
```

Any ideas are welcome

Thanks

Comment: Please could you paste the relevant part of your code?

Comment: There aren't any changes to his code so I don't know what to post, and it looks like the error comes from haystack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Python version issue. Python 3.2 does not have the `u` prefix for strings, because strings are unicode by default in Python 3. The prefix was reintroduced in Python 3.3 to make compatibility with 2.7 easier. See the [3.3 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html).

Note that the [PyPI page for Haystack 2.3.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-haystack/2.3.1) mentions 3.3+ as a requirement.

You should upgrade your Python version to 3.3.

Comment: Thanks, I have now upgraded my version of python3. My version of django is still installed for python3.2, but on reinstall pip3 installs it to python3.2, how do I install a specific version of pip3, or change the version of python it tries to install to?